# angular2 - service, json, how to access and remove a json element from service?

Tags: angular

This is how I do a get request that returns json in my service:

```
getModel(modelId:any){
    return this._authHttp.get(this.getModelUrl(modelId)).map(res => res.json());
}
```

My json object looks like this {"results"=['a']}

I am new to angular2.  How do I just return ['a']?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
getModel(modelId:any){
  return this._authHttp.get(this.getModelUrl(modelId))
             .map(res => res.json().results); // <-----
}
```